# 14.10 Software Updater Crashing

Tags: 14.10, update-manager, crash

I am aware that a few questions are around about this. But mine is somewhat different. First, it shows *Software Updater* has crashed ( different from other errors posted here ). A crash report is sent to Ubuntu every time. Also unlike in other reports, *Ubuntu Software Center* is working fine ( thankfully ).

I use to get away with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

on terminal and get most of the updates without problem. But even after trying these commands ( and `sudo apt-get update` after that ), when I run *Software Updater*, I can still see an update for Ubuntu base ( see screen shot below )

[image]

It will be nice if someone knows

1. A solution to fix the crashing issue.
2. A way to update Ubuntu base via Terminal.

Comment: Ok, there is official bug report and there seems to be no fix yet (sadly )  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1367017                                                                                   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptdaemon/+bug/1377152

Comment: Please run software updater from the command line and provide the full program output here.

Comment: To upgrade ubuntu base try running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster , share the command for the same please. However there was confirmation that such a bug exists ( see my comment ) and there is no fix yet for 14.10.

Answer (score -1):

I have only part answer to this question as of now.

Use commands

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

These should update almost every component in your setup.

Since there are bug reports and last one seems being fixed as well. I hope these 3 commands at some point will fix the issue of GUI crashing as well.

Comment: man apt-get: " ... dist-upgrade
           dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade, also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and it will attempt
           to upgrade the most important packages at the expense of less important ones if necessary. The dist-upgrade command may therefore remove some packages. The /etc/apt/sources.list file contains a list of locations ..."

Comment: @Dilip Did running those commands actually fix or help your problem. If so, how? If not (or you're not sure), and you're just trying to update your question with information about what you've tried so far, then I recommend adding the information as an edit to your question rather than as an answer. Note also that running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` does *not* by itself upgrade to a newer Ubuntu release (nor is it part of any recommended method of upgrading Ubuntu, though a *Debian* system is upgraded by editing `sources.list` for the new release and then running `apt-get dist-upgrade).

Comment: @EliahKagan, as I mentioned, I have been using apt-get update and apt-get upgrade commands since some time now ( since GUI is not working ). It does everything for regular updates. As for "  Ubuntu base " dist-upgrade does it. So combination of these 3 commands will almost keep your Ubuntu update. I am not sure what you mean by Recommended Method, but these are just command alternatives  for update in Ubuntu if you are not using aptdaemon. do-release-upgrade can be used as well.

Comment: @ByteCommander if you don't mind, kindly let me know why apt-get upgrade was removed. I would have preferred apt-get upgrade over dist-upgrade for the reasons mentioned by A.B . Also, it would have been nice to keep the bug report links in the post. People would actually know what is causing the issue.

Comment: @Dilip Because `apt-get upgrade` performs the package updates without handling changing dependencies (adding/removing dependency packages), while `apt-get dist-upgrade` is capable of handling both easy and difficult package updates. If you `dist-upgrade`, you don't need to `upgrade`, because everything is already done. If you want more explanations, please come to the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room).